# UTC date and time to local

Tags: javascript, date

I write a function to reverse UTC time to local time

```
function utcToLocal(utc){
    var t = new Date(Number(utc));
    d = [t.getFullYear(), t.getMonth(), t.getDate()].join('/');
    d += ' ' + t.toLocaleTimeString();
    return d;
}
```

but i can't confirm this code is right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to convert the UTC timestamp into a local date and just subtract the local offset (which is in minutes), so:

```
function utcToLocal(utc){
    // Create a local date from the UTC string
    var t = new Date(Number(utc));

    // Get the offset in ms
    var offset = t.getTimezoneOffset()*60000;

    // Subtract from the UTC time to get local
    t.setTime(t.getTime() - offset);

    // do whatever
    var d = [t.getFullYear(), t.getMonth(), t.getDate()].join('/');
    d += ' ' + t.toLocaleTimeString();
    return d;
}
```

Where I am, the offset is -600, so I need to subtract -36,000,000 ms from UTC time (which actually adds 36,000,000 ms).

#### Edit

I may have misunderstood the question.

The internal value of a javascript date instance is a UTC time clip in milliseconds. So if `utc` is such a time (e.g. 2012-08-19T00:00:00Z is 1345334400000), then the OP will create a date instance based on that value and  `toLocaleTimeString` will show an implementation dependent string of the local time for the supplied UTC time.

So if the local timezone offset is say -6hrs, then `alert(new Date(1345334400000)))` show something like *Sat Aug 18 2012 18:00:00 GMT-600*.

I was assuming that the OP wanted to set the local time to the same time as the UTC time, e.g. that 2012-08-19T00:00:00Z would become 2012-08-19T00:00:00 local.

Comment: The `t` object is capable of automatically forming the date string with the locale settings, there is no need for timezone offset calculations.

Comment: @Igor - given the OP, *utc* is just a number, how does JS know that it is a UTC time and not local? Date instances are based on the local timezone, so the time of the created date object needs to be adjusted for the offset. ECMA-262 15.9.1.9 is relevant.

Comment: @RobG What is this 60000? Does it differs for every timezone?

Comment: The [timezone offset](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.26) it provided in minutes. Multiplying by 60.000 converts minutes to milliseconds that can be added to the [time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) in a javascript Date object.